# How can I call a function from a Swift file and use it in a ViewController?

Tags: swift

I have a Swift file that gets details about the user that is currently logged in/signed up named `CognitoUserPoolController.swift`

```
import Foundation
import AWSCognitoIdentityProvider

class CognitoUserPoolController {

    let userPoolRegion: AWSRegionType = "Private Info"
    let userPoolID = "Private Info"
    let appClientID = "Private Info"
    let appClientSecret = "Private Info"

    var userPool:AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool?

    var currentUser:AWSCognitoIdentityUser? {
        get {
            return userPool?.currentUser()
        }
    }

    static let sharedInstance: CognitoUserPoolController = CognitoUserPoolController()

    private init() {

        let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: userPoolRegion, credentialsProvider: nil)

        let poolConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: appClientID,
                                                                        clientSecret: appClientSecret,
                                                                        poolId: userPoolID)

        AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.register(with: serviceConfiguration,
                                            userPoolConfiguration: poolConfiguration,
                                            forKey:"AWSChat")

        userPool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: "AWSChat")

        AWSDDLog.sharedInstance.logLevel = .verbose
    }



    func login(username: String, password:String, completion:@escaping (Error?)->Void) {

        let user = self.userPool?.getUser(username)
        let task = user?.getSession(username, password: password, validationData:nil)

        task?.continueWith(block: { (task: AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserSession>) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error {
                completion(error)
                return nil
            }

            completion(nil)
            return nil

        })
    }


    func signup(username: String, password:String, emailAddress:String, completion:@escaping (Error?, AWSCognitoIdentityUser?)->Void) {

        var attributes = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType]()
        let emailAttribute = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType(name: "email", value: emailAddress)
        attributes.append(emailAttribute)
        print(emailAttribute.value!)

        let task = self.userPool?.signUp(username, password: password, userAttributes: attributes, validationData: nil)

        task?.continueWith(block: {(task: AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolSignUpResponse>) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error {
                completion(error, nil)
                return nil
            }

            guard let result = task.result else {
                let error = NSError(domain: "Private Info",
                                    code: 100,
                                    userInfo: ["__type":"Unknown Error", "message":"Cognito user pool error."])
                completion(error, nil)
                return nil
            }

            completion(nil, result.user)
            return nil
        })

    }



    func confirmSignup(user: AWSCognitoIdentityUser, confirmationCode:String, completion:@escaping (Error?)->Void) {

        let task = user.confirmSignUp(confirmationCode)

        task.continueWith { (task: AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserConfirmSignUpResponse>) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error {
                completion(error)
                return nil
            }

            completion(nil)
            return nil
        }

    }

    func resendConfirmationCode(user: AWSCognitoIdentityUser, completion:@escaping (Error?)->Void) {

        let task = user.resendConfirmationCode()
        task.continueWith { (task: AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserResendConfirmationCodeResponse>) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error {
                completion(error)
                return nil
            }

            completion(nil)
            return nil
        }

    }

    func getUserDetails(user: AWSCognitoIdentityUser, completion:@escaping (Error?, AWSCognitoIdentityUserGetDetailsResponse?)->Void) {


        let task = user.getDetails()
        task.continueWith(block: { (task: AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserGetDetailsResponse>) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error {
                completion(error, nil)
                return nil
            }

            guard let result = task.result else {
                let error = NSError(domain: "Private Info",
                                    code: 100,
                                    userInfo: ["__type":"Unknown Error", "message":"Cognito user pool error."])
                completion(error, nil)
                return nil
            }

            completion(nil, result)
            return nil
        })
    }
}
```

After a user successfully signs up they are presented with `HomeViewController`. In `HomeViewController` I try to print an attribute email value like this but it does not work

```
import UIKit
import AWSCognitoIdentityProvider

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

        let userpoolController = CognitoUserPoolController.sharedInstance
        userpoolController.getUserDetails(user: userpoolController.currentUser!) { (error: Error?, details:AWSCognitoIdentityUserGetDetailsResponse?) in
          view.backgroundColor = .green // This line of code works, but below this line it does not.
            if let loggedInUserAttributes = details?.userAttributes {
                self.view.backgroundColor = .systemPink
                for attribute in loggedInUserAttributes {
                    if attribute.name?.compare("email") == .orderedSame {
                        print ("Email address of logged-in user is \(attribute.value!)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The background color successfully changes to green but does not change to pink (That was to see if the code was working.)  Inside of the `if let` statement is where the code is not working and there are not any errors. How can I properly fix this?

Comment: So `details` is nil? Or `details.userAttributes` is nil?

Comment: apparently `details?.usserAttributes` is nil